# How to identify the function of a graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am trying to identify the function of a graph in order to create a dataset for it.

Dataset as in several x/y-values that will lead Excel/PowerPoint to create a graph looking just like the drawing:

[image]

Unfortunately I am not that good in maths, so I hope that some of you might have a hint in how to find out the function of a graph from a picture.

best regards!

Comment: It looks like the density function of the log-normal distribution or inverse gamma distribution (check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)...

Comment: This  looks like a $\chi^{2}$ distribution...

Comment: Thanks guys, I will check that out and try to create some data samples to reproduce that stuff.

Comment: @jibounet Looks to me like the Inverse Gamma PDF with a=3 and b=1 is the best guess. Log-normal with o=1 could also work.

What's the best way to calculate x/y values for these buggers? Wikipedia and other pages provide the mathematical function only and I don't even know half the signs they use in there, so I guess I can't really calc it by hand. 

Are there any special websites that can do stuff like that?

Comment: Yes, the inverse gamma seems to be a good guess. I'm not sure I understand your question. In your post, you are plotting $x/y$ values as a function "Mio" ?

Comment: "Mio" is the german abbreviation for million, so basically the unit of the x-axis is in million € / $. The y-axis is the probability / frequency distribution of future credit defaults.

My question is how excatly do I get x/y value pairs that form this kind of graph? From my understanding one could calculate them from the formula on that wikipedia page, but as I am a total math failure I can't even read most of the "signs" used in the formula :) That's why I wanted to know if there are any tool assisted ways to calculate the x/y value pairs

Answer (score 0):

> *How to identify the function of a graph ?*

By experience. In my experience, the graphic of the integrand of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) looks very similar

to what I see in your picture. So my advice would be to start plotting functions of the form $A\cdot\dfrac{x^n}{e^{ax}}$

and to modify the three parameters until you obtain something sufficiently close to what is there in

the picture.